# synchronize sql server 2000 with sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I need to synchronize sql server 2000 data (source) in one server to sql server 2008 (destination) in another server by using wcf (one direction transfer is sufficient) so that i can take occasional updates from 2000 to 2008. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) is ideal for your needs if you want to do this entirely in code.

Otherwise you could set up some sql scripts to perform backups, and schedule it as required.

Comment: Hi PaulG, can the SqlBulkCopy class track the changes between the sql servers and copy only the changed data? I don't want to backup and restore entire database either.